# Deriving the time-independent form of Schrödinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The motion of particles is governed by Schrödinger's equation,

$$\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \Psi + V \Psi = i \hbar \dfrac{\partial{\Psi}}{\partial{t}},$$

where $m$ is the particle's mass, $V$ is the potential energy operator, and $(-\hbar^2/2m) \nabla^2$ is the kinetic energy operator ($= p^2/2m$).

The state function can be expressed as the product of space-dependent and time-dependent factors, $\Psi(r, t) = \psi(r) w(t)$. If we substitute this into Shrödinger's equation, we get

$$\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m}w \nabla^2 \psi(r) + V \psi(r) w(t) = i \hbar \psi \dfrac{\partial{w}}{\partial{t}}$$

Upon dividing by $w(t)$, we get

$$\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi(r) + V \psi(r) = i \hbar \dfrac{\psi}{w(t)} \dfrac{\partial{w(t)}}{\partial{t}}.$$

But the time-independent Shrödinger equation is said to actually be

$$\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi(r) + V \psi(r) = E \psi.$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain what I did incorrectly here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't do anything incorrectly. You just haven't pushed far enough. You can write the last equation in your derivation as 
$$\frac{1}{\psi(r)}\bigg[\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi(r) + V \psi(r)\bigg] = i \hbar \frac{1}{w(t)} \dfrac{\partial{w(t)}}{\partial{t}}$$
Since the LHS and the RHS of this equation are independent of $t$ and $r$ respectively, they can be equal for some $\Psi(r,t)$ only if they are individually equal to a constant (think about it: otherwise, if I were to vary $r$ a little bit while keeping $t$ constant, the LHS would change but the RHS wouldn't and the equality wouldn't hold, so the conclusion is that each side should be equal to a constant, a constant that is independent of both $r$ and $t$). Let's call this constant $E$ (we will soon see that this is, in fact, the eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian, and thus, energy).

Thus, we say  $$\frac{1}{\psi(r)}\bigg[\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi(r) + V \psi(r)\bigg] =E$$

This is the so-called time-independent Schr$\ddot{\text{o}}$dinger equation. As you can see, it is simply the eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V$ and thus, the eigenvalue is rightly denoted by $E$!

Comment: Using two lowercase psi's is confusing.

Comment: As a result there is a problem with your second line.

Comment: @A.Bordg Many thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So $E$ is the energy of the system (such as the particle in question, if that's what we use the Shrödinger equation to model)?

Comment: @ThePointer E is the energy of an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, in particular, the $\psi(r)$. You can describe a particle which can be in a superposition of multiple such eigenstates and thus doesn't have a specific energy. But yes, if you want to describe a particle that has a specific energy, the E would be the energy of that particle and the spatial part of the wavefunction would have to follow the eigenvalue equation of the Hamiltonian (the last equation in my answer) with the eigenvalue E.

Comment: @ThePointer, I wrote an answer that you might find helpful with regards to the quesiton in your comment.

Answer (score 4):

As another answer points out, you didn't finish your separation of variables approach leading to the time independent Schrodinger equation (TISE).

However, there is another route to the TISE that *might* be of interest here.

First, the motivation for this problem is to find the *wavefunctions that have definite values E of the (total) energy observable H*. That is, we want to find the wavefunctions $\psi_E(x,t)$ that satisfy

$$H\psi_E(x,t)=E\psi_E(x,t)$$

where (working in 1D for simplicity here)

$$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x)$$

But the time dependent Schrodinger equation (TDSE) is

$$H\psi(x,t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x,t)$$

so the wavefunctions we seek satisfy

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_E(x,t)=-i\frac{E}{\hbar}\psi_E(x,t)$$

and it's easy to see that these wavefunctions are of the form

$$\psi_E(x,t)=e^{-i\frac{E}{\hbar}t}\psi_E(x,0)$$

where $\psi_E(x,0)=\psi_E(x)$ is a function of $x$ only. Now, put this back into the TDSE. First, note that:

$$H\psi_E(x,t)=He^{-i\frac{E}{\hbar}t}\psi_E(x)=e^{-i\frac{E}{\hbar}t}H\psi_E(x)$$

and

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_E(x,t)=i\hbar\left(-i\frac{E}{\hbar}\right)e^{-i\frac{E}{\hbar}t}\psi_E(x)=e^{-i\frac{E}{\hbar}t}E\psi_E(x)$$

thus, after cancelling the common factor $e^{-i\frac{E}{\hbar}t}$, we have the TISE:

$$H\psi_E(x)=E\psi_E(x)$$

In summary, the solutions $\psi_E(x)$ of the TISE are the *spatially dependent* part of the wavefunctions $\psi_E(x,t)$ that have definite values $E$ of the energy observable $H$.

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. So $H$ is actually an operator?

Comment: @ThePointer, yes, I thought you knew this (from reading your question). The classical Hamiltonian (total energy) for a particle in potential is $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$. The QM Hamiltonian *operator* is $H=\frac{P^2}{2m} + V(X)$ where $P$ is the momentum operator and $X$ is the position operator. On the position (wavefunction) basis, the Hamiltonian operator takes the form in your question. TDSE is a *non-trivial* statement about the Hamiltonian operator: *the Hamiltonian is the generator of time evolution*

Comment: "So the wavefunctions we seek satisfy $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_E(x,t) = -i\frac{E}{\hbar}\psi_E(x,t)$" Why is this the case? I don't understand your reasoning here.

Comment: @ThePointer, that's just the result of combining the 1st and 3rd equations, i.e., $H\psi_E(t)=E\psi_E(t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_E(t)$

Comment: I see what you meant. But I think that the problem is that you have $\psi_E$ everywhere, and then for equation 3 you have $\psi$, so it is unclear. Notice that you just added the $E$ subscript in your comment above, but it would otherwise be $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{-i E}{\hbar} \psi_E$$

Comment: @ThePointer, no, that's not how it works. Equation 3 is general (holds for *any* $\psi$). Equation 1 holds only those $\psi$ that are eignenfunctions of the energy operator, i.e., that 'pass through' the operator with scaling factor $E$. The subscript is just a *label* to help keep everything straight.

Comment: @ThePointer, note that it's more or less customary to label state vectors (whether an abstract ket or a position basis wave function) with their eigenvalue if they are eigenkets of an observable. For example, using abstract kets, you'll see something like $N|n\rangle=n|n\rangle$ or $X|x\rangle=x|x\rangle$. A general ket, on the other hand, is often denoted by $|\psi\rangle$

Comment: Hmm, ok. I now understand all of the mathematics in your answer, but I think that, since I am a novice to quantum mechanics, I am not understanding the physical point that you're trying to make. I now understand everything you did here, but if I'm not mistaken, there is a deeper physical point about the energy $E$ that you're trying to make here, and that is lost on me (again, likely because I have not yet developed the necessary level of physical understanding of the mathematics).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. At the moment, as you probably saw in my other (now deleted, since it was apparently off-topic) question, I am now trying to understand how to derive the general solution of the TISE. Unfortunately, the documents I come across are lengthy discussions on the Shrödinger equation in general, and do not seem to go into detail on deriving the TISE general solution (example: https://homepage.univie.ac.at/reinhold.bertlmann/pdfs/T2_Skript_Ch_4.pdf).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108848/discussion-between-alfred-centauri-and-the-pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand where the time independent and dependent Schrodinger equation comes from, as they are both sides of the same coin. Let's first set $\hbar  = 1 $ for simplicity. Time evolution of a state actually has a specific form - we can evolve the state with what we call a  Hamiltonian $H$ by attaching an exponential term
$$ \Psi(x, t) = \psi (x) e ^{ - i H t} .$$ When we make states dependent on time below, we say we are working in the Schrodinger picture. It is easy to check that this satisfies the equation 
$$  i \frac{ \partial \Psi }{\partial t} = H \Psi .$$ This is where the time-dependent equation you know and love comes from, and as you may notice, as you have written above, our Hamiltonian is precisely 
$$ H =  - \frac{ \hbar ^ 2 }{2m} \nabla ^ 2 + V ( x)$$
Now to answer your question. It's not at all obvious what we could even split states and separate them into their time and spatial components as above. However, in your context, we assume we can. The spatial part $\psi$ is thus called a **stationary state** since we assume it doesn't depend on time and we also make the assumption that this state is an **eigenstate** of the Hamiltonian. Crucially, our energy is *defined* to be the **eigenvalue** of the Hamiltonian acting on the stationary on its own. So, we get that 
$$ H \psi ( x  ) = E \psi ( x )  = \left[ - \frac{ \hbar ^ 2 }{2m} \nabla ^ 2 + V ( x)\right] \psi(x). $$ This set of eigenstates are the states which end up being physically observable - they form a basis of all states and when we observe a system we observe precisely one of these energy eigenstates.